# Swift search Array/NSArray for multiple values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray

Two faceted question:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
contains(array, 0) // false

var array2: NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2.containsObject(4) // true
```

Is there any way to search an Array for more than 1 value? ie. Can I write below to search the array for multiple values and return true if any of the values are found? Second part to the question is how can I do that for an NSArray as well?

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
contains(array, (0,2,3)) // this doesn't work of course but you get the point
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option would be to use a `Set` for the search terms:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
let searchTerms: Set = [0,2,3]
!searchTerms.isDisjointWith(array)
```

(You have to negate the value of `isDisjointWith`, as it returns `false` when at least one of the terms is found.)

Note that you could also extend `Array` to add a shorthand for this:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func containsAny(searchTerms: Set<Element>) -> Bool {
        return !searchTerms.isDisjointWith(self)
    }
}
array.containsAny([0,2,3])
```

As for the `NSArray`, you can use the version of `contains` which takes a block to determine the match:

```
var array2: NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2.contains { searchTerms.contains(($0 as! NSNumber).integerValue) }
```

Explanation of closure syntax (as requested in comments): you can put the closure outside the `()` of method call if it's the last parameter, and if it's the only parameter you can omit the `()` altogether. `$0` is the default name of the first argument to the closure (`$1` would be the second, etc). And `return` may be omitted if the closure is only one expression. The long equivalent:

```
array2.contains({ (num) in
    return searchTerms.contains((num as! NSNumber).integerValue)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Arkku, coule you please explain how the NSArray array2.contains line works? I am pretty new to programming, it looks like you're using a closure shorthand but if you could explain how that works it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can chain contains together with a second array:

```
// Swift 1.x
contains(array) { contains([0, 2, 3], $0) }

// Swift 2 (as method)
array.contains{ [0, 2, 3].contains($0) }

// and since Xcode 7 beta 2 you can pass the contains function which is associated to the array ([0, 2, 3])
array.contains([0, 2, 3].contains)

// Xcode 12
array.contains(where: [0, 2, 3].contains)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.7 +**

A quick syntax fix to the accepted answer for the latest version of swift:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func containsAny(searchTerms: Set<Element>) -> Bool {
        return !searchTerms.isDisjoint(with: self)
    }
}
```